# Disable scrolling when iron-overlay is open and set to with-backdrop

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am using iron-overlay-behavior with backdrop-set. But when overlay opens user can still scroll the underlying div, which on closing the overlay changes the content position and becomes confusing.
Any suggestion on how should I block scroll events getting bubbled down to div below?
Also lease note I have set

```js
        Polymer.setPassiveTouchGestures(true);
```

So cant block the events.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be right answer by design but works:

```js
 openoverlay()
      {
        this.$.backdrop.open();
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';

      }
     
      closeoverlay()
      {
        this.$.backdrop.close();
        document.body.style.overflow = '';

      }
```